# POST Multiple Parameters To PHP To MYSQL Database

Tags: php, ios, mysql, post

For the life of me, I can't seem to figure out why this is happening. We are sending the body from an ios app to a php backend POST API that writes to a MYSQL server. We have printed out the request body to a txt file and it is clearly getting all the data, but when we attempt to store it, it fails every time. If we send data that does not contain a Base64 Encoded String from the iOS App, it stores to the database fine. We are attempting to store the Base64 String in Longtext format:

```
<?php
include('db_connect.php');
$http_data = file_get_contents('php://input'); //This is json data
$data = json_decode($http_data);

$b64img1 = $data->img1; //A Base64 Encoded String
$b64img2 = $data->img2; //A Base64 Encoded String
$img1 = $data->img1Title;
$img2 = $data->img2Title;
$cat = $data->category;
$user = $data->userID;
$current = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$time = $data->length;
$length = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time() + $time);
$postID = $current . '_' . $user . '_' . $length;

$loc = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE BINARY userID = '$user';");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($loc);
$location = $row['location'];
$numPosts = $row['post_number'];
$posts = $row['postIDs'];
$newNum = $numPosts + 1;
$newPosts = $posts . $postID . ', ';

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `content` (`postID`,`img1`,`img2`,`img1title`,`img2title`,`category`,`user`,`location`,`postUntil`) VALUES ('$postID','$b64img1','$b64img2','$img1','$img2','$cat','$user','$location','$length');");
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET post_number = '$newNum', postIDs = '$newPosts' WHERE BINARY userID = '$user';");
echo "{\"Success\":\"Yes\"}";
mysql_close($con);
exit;
?>
```

Here is the iOS code that we are using to send to our POST API...

```
NSData *dataImage = [[NSData alloc] init];
NSData *dataImage2 = [[NSData alloc] init];
UIImage *selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

dataImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(selectedImage);
NSString *image = [dataImage base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];

dataImage2 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(selectedImage);
NSString *image2 = [dataImage2 base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];


NSDictionary *dictionaryOrArrayToOutput = @{@"img1" : image,
                                            @"img2" : image2,
                                            @"img1title" : titleOne,
                                            @"img2title" : titleTwo,
                                            @"category" : category,
                                            @"userID" : userID,
                                            @"length" : time};

NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionaryOrArrayToOutput
                                                   options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                     error:&error];

if (! jsonData)
{
    NSLog(@"Got an error: %@", error);
}
else
{
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", jsonString);

    NSData *postData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:SAMPLEURL]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLResponse *requestResponse;
    NSData *requestHandler = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&requestResponse error:nil];

    NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[requestHandler bytes] length:[requestHandler length] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"REPLY FROM SERVER: %@", requestReply);
}
```

Does anyone see something wrong, or can point me in the right direction? This is driving me insane, and can't seem to find a reason why this isn't working.

Comment: Break the problem up a little. Insure you are correctly POSTing the JSON to the server, use Charles Proxy to verify that. On the server as soon as the data is received log it,  and log it after de-serializing it, insure you have the correct data at those points. Then if all that is correct look at the MySQL code. If there are still problems add the log results to the question.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thoughts:

1. You should temporarily echo/print all of your variable values and put them in the response so you can confirm that everything was successfully found. And log the SQL, too.

   For example, I notice that the capitalization of a few fields doesn't match (e.g. `img1Title` vs `img1title`.
2. You should check the result of your SQL calls and report errors. For example, the `mysql_query` documentation suggests:

   ```
   $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM TEST');
   if (!$result) {
       die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
   }
   ```

   I usually add the error message to a JSON response, but you get the idea: Check your return values.

As an aside:

1. You really should be use `mysqli_query` (or `PDO::query`) as `mysql_query` is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.
2. You really should be quoting your values with `mysqli_real_escape_string` (or I'd prefer binding column values with `mysqli_stmt_bind_param`). As it is, your code is susceptible to SQL injection attacks.
3. BTW, when you start building your response to include SQL errors in JSON, you might find it easier (and more robust) to use `json_encode` rather than building your JSON response yourself.
4. Also, if you're providing JSON response, the PHP should specify the `Content-Type` of the response:

   ```
   header("Content-Type: application/json");
   ```
5. In your iOS code, there's some stylistic stuff there, too:

   - You are instantiating `dataImage1` and `dataImage2` and then discarding those two objects when you use `UIImagePNGRepresentation`.
   - You don't have to create `postBody`. You still have `jsonData`, so why reconvert the logged string back again?
   - You don't have to create `Content-Length` because `NSURLConnection` does that for you.
   - You shouldn't be using synchronous network requests. Use the asynchronous renditions.